# How to fetch billing info for Google Cloud Platform using python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Can we fetch the billing info for our projects using Billing API using python client libraries? For example if I wanted to know the cost incurred with each VM for a specified month, how would I should do it?

Comment: You must first enable billing export to BigQuery. Then use a Python SQL client to query billing data exported to BigQuery. Billing data becomes available after enabling export, previous data is not exported.

Comment: Is there any way apart from big query?

Comment: Google does not provide an API to fetch billing cost details. You must export the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the document [Python Client for Cloud Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudbilling/latest):

> Cloud billing API: allows developers to manage their billing accounts
> or browse the catalog of SKUs and pricing.

In order to use this library, you first need to go through the following steps:

1. Select or create a Cloud Platform project.
2. Enable billing for your project.
3. Enable the Cloud Billing API.
4. Setup Authentication.

Also refer to this document on [Cloud Billing Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/libraries).

Update:

As @John hanley mentioned , Google does not provide an API to fetch billing cost details.

You have to enable [Cloud Billing data export to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-setup).

> To export Cloud Billing data to BigQuery, take the following steps:
>
> 1. Create a project where the Cloud Billing data will be stored, and enable billing on the project (if you have not already done so).
> 2. Configure permissions on the project and on the Cloud Billing account.
> 3. Enable the BigQuery Data Transfer Service API (required to export your pricing data).
> 4. Create a BigQuery dataset in which to store the data.
> 5. Enable Cloud Billing export of cost data and pricing data to be written into the dataset.

Comment: Yes, there is cloud billing API but it doesn't calculate the billing for my VM instances and returns it. It just shows the cost per unit time.